# mysql range clause with month and date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to define a frame using the range clause. Here's my code:

```
select dt,
       pair_ticker,
       close,
       min(dt) over(partition by pair_ticker order by dt range between interval 3 month  
       and -1 day preceding and current row) as prev_date
from klines_1d
```

My intention is to start the frame 3 months and deduct 1 day from that. So for ex., current row is sept 25, the the beginning of the frame should be june 26. The code produces errors obviously because of the syntax error in combining the month and day. How do you fix this one?

Comment: Try  `BETWEEN INTERVAL 3 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND ...`

Comment: @rick james. Still a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

According to [Window Function Frame Specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html):

> For expr PRECEDING (and expr FOLLOWING), expr can be a ? parameter marker (for use in a prepared statement), a nonnegative numeric literal, ***or a temporal interval of the form `INTERVAL val unit`***.

The complete units list is provided in [Expressions: Temporal Intervals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals). And there is no unit which includes both month and day value. The reason is simple - this unit is ambiguous, the result of its applying may depend on the parts applying order. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YaFkH2ij).

Possible solutions:

```sql
ORDER BY dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 3 MONTH PRECEDING
               AND     INTERVAL 1 DAY   PRECEDING
```

or

```sql
ORDER BY dt - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 DAY   FOLLOWING
               AND     INTERVAL 3 MONTH FOLLOWING
```

**These solutions produces different results!** So you must select those which matches your logic.

Comment: these show error codes when run.

Comment: @jomx99 Provide a fiddle which reproduces the problem. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: RANGE BETWEEN with a date range isn't supported by all databases - for instance, MariaDb doesn't https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9727

Comment: @TerryHorner *RANGE BETWEEN with a date range isn't supported by all databases* ??? https://dbfiddle.uk/8ODCnxaq (MySQL), https://dbfiddle.uk/AJrCD4yg (PostgreSQL). *for instance, MariaDb doesn't* - the question is tagged for MySQL..