# Getting previous row values and comparing it to the current row in mysql

Tags: mysql

So I want to calculate the three month performance of certain stocks.

Here's a portion of the raw table:

| dt | stock | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | abc | 100 |
| 2022-09-01 | xyz | 50 |
| 2022-09-02 | abc | 110 |
| 2022-09-02 | xyz | 55 |
| 2022-09-03 | abc | 120 |
| 2022-09-03 | xyz | 60 |

My goal was to make a table like this:

| dt | stock | price | prev_date | prev_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

So far, the progress I've made is to calculate the prev_date using the ff code

```
select dt,
       stock,
       price,
       nth_value(dt, 2) over (partition by stock 
       order by dt range between interval 3 month preceding
       and current row) as prev_date
from tbl_stocks
```

| dt | stock | price | prev_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | abc | 100 | 2022-06-02 |
| 2022-09-01 | xyz | 50 | 2022-06-02 |
| 2022-09-02 | abc | 110 | 2022-06-03 |
| 2022-09-02 | xyz | 55 | 2022-06-03 |
| 2022-09-03 | abc | 120 | 2022-06-04 |
| 2022-09-03 | xyz | 60 | 2022-06-04 |

Been trying various self-joins and subqueries to return the price for the previous date but to no avail.

Comment: `dt - INTERVAL 3 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS prev_date` https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317415/

Comment: Maybe:  `LAG(1)`?

Comment: @RickJames can't do with lag() as not every frame has the same no of items. For example, some stocks could be suspended on some dates while others were Trading.

Comment: @Akina already taken cared the prev_date. Getting the price of the stock  indicated by the prev_date is where I need help.

Comment: @jomx99 - Please include an example of that in your sample data.  Also provide the _desired_ output of the query.